# Refresh Token with JWT - JWTUtils Cannot set user authentication because "this.jwtUtils" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, refresh-token

I have a problem about fix the error in my Refresh Token with JWT in Spring Boot Application.

My issue is related with validating JWT Token.

Even if I defined @Component annotation in JWTUtil class, the issue cannot be disappeared.

Here is my error shown below.

```
AuthTokenFilter | doFilterInternal | Cannot set user authentication: Cannot invoke "com.refreshtokenjwt.app.jwt.JwtUtils.validateJwtToken(String)" because "this.jwtUtils" is null
```

How can I fix my issue?

Here is my JWTUtils shown below.

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.secret.expireMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(CustomUserDetails userPrincipal) {
        return generateTokenFromUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());
    }

    public String generateTokenFromUsername(String username) {
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JwtUtils | validateJwtToken | JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my AuthTokenFilter class shown below.

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    public AuthTokenFilter() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public AuthTokenFilter(JwtUtils jwtUtils, CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            LOGGER.error("AuthTokenFilter | doFilterInternal | jwt: {}", jwt);

            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {

                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("AuthTokenFilter | doFilterInternal | Cannot set user authentication: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my AuthEntryPointJwt class shown below.

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOGGER.error("AuthEntryPointJwt | commence | Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

        LOGGER.info("AuthEntryPointJwt | commence | status: {}", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        LOGGER.info("AuthEntryPointJwt | commence | error: {}", "Unauthorized");
        LOGGER.info("AuthEntryPointJwt | commence | message: {}", authException.getMessage());
        LOGGER.info("AuthEntryPointJwt | commence | path: {}", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);

    }
}
```

Here is my WebSecurityConfig class shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;;

    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/pages/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this

```
@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}
```

You are using the wrong constructor to create a bean, and expecting that the dependency injection will do its magic afterwards - it's not how it works.

Basically I would delete the no-args constructor in the filter, and rewrite the above method like this:

```
@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter(JwtUtils jwtUtils, CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
    return new AuthTokenFilter(jwtUtils, customUserDetailsService);
}
```